# How to spread a table into another one

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a legacy table

```
create table table1 (col1 int);
insert into table1 values(1);
insert into table1 values(2);
insert into table1 values(3);

SELECT * FROM table1;
1
2
3
```

now it gets a new column

```
alter table table1 add column col2 int;
alter table table1  ADD CONSTRAINT unique1 UNIQUE (col2);

SELECT * FROM table1;
1;null
2;null
3;null
```

then we have another table

```
create table table2 (col1 int);
insert into table2 values(7);
insert into table2 values(8);
insert into table2 values(9);

SELECT * FROM table2;
7
8
9
```

now we want to spread the values of table 2 into table1.col2

```
UPDATE table1 up
SET col2 = (SELECT col1
            FROM table2 t2
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col2=t2.col1)
            LIMIT 1);
```

but the update statement does not see the already updated rows

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique1"

Any ideas how to do that? It would be ok, if table1 remains with some rows col2=null if table2 has less rows than table1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems much easier with a `join`:

```
with t2 as (
      select t2.*, row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     )
update table1 t1
    set col2 = t2.col1
    from t2
    where t1.col1 = t2.seqnum;
```

If `col1` in `table1` is not strictly sequential, you can still do this:

```
with t2 as (
      select t2.*, row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ),
     t1 as (
      select t1.*, row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     )
update table1 toupdate
    set col2 = t2.col1
    from t1 join
         t2
         on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum
    where toupdate.col1 = t1.col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a solution

```
WITH rownumbers AS (
    SELECT col1, row_number() over (partition by 1 ORDER BY col1) FROM table1
)
UPDATE table1 up SET col2 = 
    (SELECT col1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col2=t2.col1) 
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET (
            SELECT row_number-1 FROM rownumbers WHERE col1=up.col1
    )
)
```

any cons about it?